# setTimeOut jquery problem

Tags: jquery, settimeout

i would like to scroll the window to the top, pause my animation for 1 second, and then use a fadeOut to erase the content, but this code doesn't work, do you know why?

```
$('#link').bind('click', function(){
    preloading.show();

    $('html,body').animate({'scrollTop':0}, 300, function(){
        $('#myDiv').setTimeout(function(){
            $(this).empty()
                .append(conteneurBio).hide()
                .fadeIn('slow', function(){
                    preloading.hide();
                });
        }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: You can you define "doesn't work"?  What DOES it do?

Comment: My suspicious nature begs me to put a `console.log(this)` in the setTimout() callback, just to make sure it is what I think it is.

Comment: `setTimeout` is a global function, not a jQuery method.

Comment: @kingjiv : thanks guys for your answers, kingjiv there was a bug the new content didn't appear inside the div. Tomm's answer works fine. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't this work too?

```
$('html,body').animate({'scrollTop':0}, 300, function() {
        $('#myDiv')
             .empty()
             .hide()
             .append(conteneurBio)             
             .delay(1000)
             .fadeIn('slow', function() { preloading.hide(); }
    });
```

Comment: +1 This one looks like the only solution that has a chance at actually working.

Comment: @Tomm : thanks Tomm, it works really fine, i tried it at first but i guess i missed something. Last thing, i'd like to use a fadeOut() before the empty() method, i tried to put it just before empty() but the result is (in that order) : empty() / fadeIn() / fadeOut() then another fadeIn() ... ? any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're missing one set of closing `});`s:

```
$('#link').bind('click', function(){
    preloading.show();

    $('html,body').animate({'scrollTop':0}, 300, function()
    {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#myDiv').empty()
                .append(conteneurBio).hide()
                .fadeIn('slow', function(){
                    preloading.hide();
                });
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: -1 This code wouldn't work either for a couple reasons.  `setTimeout` isn't a jQuery method and `this` is is set to the `window` object when setTimeout fires so you can't use it inside the `setTimeout` function to refer to some previous DOM or jQuery object.  The OP really needs to be looking at javascript errors in the error console.

Comment: @jfriend00: Can you explain in more detail? Seems to be working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/HMJEn/

Comment: Yes, local variables like the one in your jsFiddle are available inside the setTimeout, but NOT `'this`.  That is reset by the javascript engine before invoking the setTimeout callback.  See this jsFiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/akxuz/.

Comment: @jfriend00: You're right. I completely glossed over the fact that he was using `$(this)`. I updated my code. Thanks.

Comment: I still like Tomm's method below that uses .delay() instead of setTimeout, and you seem to have dropped the `$('#myDiv')` reference which I think was relevant, but you're on a better track now.

Comment: @jfriend00: I didn't understand what the OP was trying to do. Now that I do, I updated my code once again. However, Tomm's method below run's `.empty().hide().append(conteneurBio)` before the delay, which is clearly not what the OP had in mind...

Comment: @Joseph Silber : thanks Joseph, i didn't put the entire code, Tomm's answer was good for the delay, i tried with the delay at first but i guess i missed something. Now it works fine, thanks guys for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

used something like: http://jsbeautifier.org/
it helps you find any missing brackets/braces in your javascript, especially when you don't have an editor that does the indentation for you.

Joseph posted before me with the correct answer though, you're missing a "});" at the end